# Определение связей второстепенных членов с однородными членами

Tags: словосочетания, однородные-члены, подчинительная-связь

Давно висит это вопрос, всё ещё не получил исчерпывающего ответа с ссылками на правила. Общий вопрос заключается в следующием.

Как в предложениях или словосочетаниях с однородными членами понять: обстоятельство или дополнение относится ко всем однородным членам или только в ближайшему?

1) **Делать достойным похвалы, признания или подтверждения заслуг.**

Слово "заслуг" зависит только от "подтверждения" или и от "подтверждения", и от "признания"?

2) **Нужно его осилить и победить в честной борьбе.**

«В честной борьбе» относится только к «осилить» или и к «победить», и к «осилить»? Мне подсказывают, что есть правила, гласящее, что зависимое слово всегда относится ко всем однородным сказуемым. Так ли это?

3) **Мне бы понять основную идею и посыл.**

С этим случаем я разобрался самостоятельно: определение относится только к первому или ко всем однородным членам исходя из смысла. Для предотвращения двоякости понимания определение нередко ставится во множественном числе, если оно относится ко всем однородным членам.

4) **определение, выраженное причастием или прилагательным с зависимыми словами»**

С зависимыми словами и причастие, и прилагательное или только прилагательное?

5) **Когда возникают проблемы, он быстро оценивает обстановку и принимает решение.**

Обстоятельство "быстро" относится только к сказуемому "оценивает" или к "принимает решение" тоже?

6) **Тактика «сказал — доказал» сильно поднимает вас в глазах HR-менеджера и выделяет среди конкурентов.**

То же самое касательно обстоятельства "сильно": оно относится только к сказуемому "поднимает" или к "выделяет" тоже?

Хотелось бы получить ссылки на какие-то правила про то, как, кроме контекста, определяется связь второстепенных членов с однородными членами? Как на это влияет вид подчинительной связи, тип союза (сочинительный, разделительный, ...), наличие запятой, положение зависимого слова по отношению к однородным "кандидатам" на главные (перед или после) и т.д.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Изучение грамматики на придуманных примерах — дело абсолютно бессмысленное. Нужно брать цитаты из  печатных (проверенных) изданий.
2. Если возникает вопрос о том, к чему относится второстепенный член, то такая неясность является недостатком текста и требует редактирования.
3. Конкретно по примерам:

1) Делать достойным похвалы, признания или подтверждения заслуг.

Смысл неясен. Что такое "достойным подтверждения заслуг"?

2) Нужно его осилить и победить в честной борьбе.

Осилить и победить — не слишком удачные синонимы.

3) Мне бы понять основную идею и посыл.

Основной посыл? Посыл — это суждение, служащее основанием для вывода. Он не может быть основным, да еще соединяться с идеей.

4) определение, выраженное причастием или прилагательным с зависимыми словами

Грамматика неясная, требует редактирования.

5) Когда возникают проблемы, он быстро оценивает обстановку// и принимает решение.

Наречие "быстро" сочетается с ближайшим глаголом. Это видно даже по интонационному членению текста.

6) Тактика «сказал — доказал» сильно поднимает вас в глазах HR-менеджера// и выделяет среди конкурентов.

Наречие "сильно"  (лучше сказать:  значительно) также относится к первому глаголу, а со вторым вообще не сочетается по смыслу.

Надеюсь, что Вы теперь понимаете, что грамматические связи надо изучать не на собственных примерах, которые сами по себе могут быть ошибочными.

Comment: Посылка (основание для вывода) может быть основной. Но я не думаю, что здесь "посыл" употреблено в значении "посылка", а не "побуждение".

Comment: Возможно и так, но даже не в этом дело. Насколько я помню, в таких конструкциях ОБЩЕЕ прилагательное может стоять в форме ед. числа, согласуясь с ближайшим определением. Так что по форме согласования семантику не определишь. Пример опять же не из удачных.

Comment: По сути ответа я не спорю и ответ в целом поддержал. (А подобные комментарии я оставляю не с целью придирок, а только в тех случаях, когда уверен, что для будущих читателей они будут полезны.)

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку. Да, есть еще значение  (посыл - это внутреннее побуждение, импульс). А можно ли этот посыл соединять с идеей союзом И? Мне кажется, у них скорее не внешняя, а внутренняя связь. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ну, я свою точку зрения по этому поводу высказал. А дальше спорить вряд ли стоит. Этот сайт типа справки, он не предназначен и не приспособлен к ведению активных обсуждений (и это не поощряется правилами форума). Если это Вам важно/интересно, лучше создать отдельную тему, но и там каждый выскажет свою точку зрения, а возможности пообщаться будут ограничены.

Comment: Под "посылом" имелся в виду месседж, мысль, которую хотят донести.

Comment: "Сильно выделяет среди конкурентов" — почему не сочетается? У "сильно" одно из значений как раз "значительно".

Comment: Сильно выделяет - не самое лучшее сочетание, как и значительно выделяет (есть в них разговорный оттенок).  Хорошие сочетание: выделять резко, ярко. Можно сказать: в значительной степени. А в недавно обсуждаемом вопросе речь шла о сравнительное степени (сильно лучше, сильно дешевле).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы ищете некую универсальную "отмычку" к предложениям такого типа, то ваши усилия напрасны. Вы не найдете формальных правил, помогающих однозначно понимать написанное. Часть из таких предложений можно понять однозначно благодаря тем или иным деталям, другие могут быть построены так, что допускают разные толкования. Продуктивен лишь противоположный подход: научиться строить предложения так, чтобы в них не было неоднозначности.

Answer (score 1):

Не слишком удачные в смысловом отношении примеры (неясно, как можно кого-то сделать достойным похвалы, что такое подтверждение заслуг и чем осиливание кого-то отличается от победы над ним же), но о связях слов догадаться можно, опираясь на смысловое правдоподобие и некоторые грамматические связи:

a) "заслуги" зависят от обоих слов (ещё не признанные признаются или уже признанные подтверждаются);

б) "в честной борьбе" относится к "победить" (как часть устойчивого сочетания "победить в честной борьбе"), в то время как "осилить" здесь может иметь буквальный смысл преодоления силы соперника;

в) "основную" относится к "идее", ввиду согласования по роду только с ней.

Comment: а) "Признания" может иметься в виду как "положительная оценка кого-либо со стороны какой-либо группы людей".

Comment: C "признанием" всё понятно, "подтверждение заслуг" излишне казённо звучит (можно признать заслуги и подтвердить факт признания заслуг, а не "подтвердить заслуги").

Comment: Я имею в виду, что "признания" не относится к слову "заслуг".
И кстати, в б) разве нет правила, что зависимое слово всегда относится ко всем однородным сказуемым?

Comment: А в случае в) согласование может быть только с первым словом (но относиться к обоим), когда по смыслу высказывания ясно, что определение характеризует не только ближайшее существительное, но и все последующие, например: "Дикий гусь и утка прилетели первыми"
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-167.htm

Comment: Если рассматривать такой смысл (по предыд. комментарию), то "признание заслуг" выпадает из независимого ряда (оно не существует вне контекста признания заслуг) и теряет смысл - тогда надо его чем-то самодостаточным и вразуметельным заменять. Не стоит из грамматических правил и терминов смысл извлекать.

Comment: Слово "признание" имеет также дефиницию "положительная оценка кого-либо со стороны какой-либо группы людей" и имеет самодостаточный смысл, не требуя после себя дополнения. Например: "Он получил наше признание". Не согласны?